# Why does extracting an archive in Flutter show files not in the archive that are prefixed with _.?

Tags: gzip, tar

I have a tar + gzipped file I download and decompress/extract in a Flutter app. The extraction code looks like this:

```
final gzDecoder = GZipDecoder();
final tar = await gzDecoder.decodeBytes(file.readAsBytesSync());
final tarDecoder = TarDecoder();
final archive = tarDecoder.decodeBytes(tar);
for (final file in archive) {
    print(file)
    ...
```

When I print out all the files in the archive like above, I see things like:

```
./question_7815.mp3
./._question_7814.mp3
```

where the original archive only has `./question_7815.mp3` (not the file prefixed with a `._`.

Furthermore, when printing the file size (`print(file.size)`) I see that the files prefixed with `._` are not the same size, so they do in fact appear to be different files, and they are much smaller.

Anyone know why this happens and potentially how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the Apple Double format, so that tar file is almost certainly originally coming from a Mac. The underscore file contains extended attribute information. You don't necessarily need to prevent it. You can just ignore those files, or exclude them during extraction. It is possible to not include them when tarring on the Mac side as well with the `--no-mac-metadata` option to tar.

Comment: That did it but the odd thing is when I untar on my mac, I don't see those files. That really threw me off. Thanks!

Comment: Of course you don't. They get stored as extended attributes on the main file.